# How to remove the commands from a gdb break point?

Tags: filter, gdb, command, break, points

I know in gdb, I can set

```
break 14
```

To break at line 14, this is the "1" break point, then

```
commands 1
printf "%d\n",i
end
```

This will attach gdb commands to break point 1. No problem.

But my question is: seems commands are co-exist with break point, as I use "i b" to check its information. In the case above:

> 1. How can I remove the commands from break point 1, and still keep the break point?
> 2. How to list/filter all commands information, without search all break points information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the commands from a breakpoint by entering an empty command list:

```
commands 1
end
```

will remove the commands from breakpoint 1.

As far as I know there's no way to list or filter the breakpoint commands other than looking at the output of `info breakpoints`.